# Kurento screen sharing seems to have reliability problems

Tags: webrtc, kurento, screensharing

I am working on a screensharing product which is to use Kurento Media Server. Everything seems to work fine, but i have one computer on which the media capture is unreliable. Most of the time it works, but sometimes it doesn't (it looks like the stream was captured but a connecting client can't see it), all difference i could see from the logs when it works vs when it's not is that instead of these lines in SDP

```
c=IN IP4 192.168.56.1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.56.1 62931 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3350409123 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.0.101 62932 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2085243720 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.1.70 62933 typ host generation 0
```

there is just this

```
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
```

(there are dozens more lines before and after that, but apart from obviously random IDs and passwords which are generated new each time, they seem to be identical)

When i share a webcam, it always works.

When it works, it works (meaning: any number of clients can connect and watch the screenshare for as long as needed, connection is always successful and reliable). When it doesn't work, no client could ever connect. So it is a definitely a problem on the transmission/capture side, not a bug of the viewer.

Is there any 'official' sample code on how to do screensharing in Kurento? For example, 'kurento-one2many' example (https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-one2many-call) which does screensharing instead of webcam sharing would be great.

This problem reproduces on just one machine so far, others including those in the same local network are working great. So i think if i try to debug it i may spend months, as it is a very subtle issue. So i just need someone who 'knows' how to do it in officially 'correct' way.

I can provide any info to help resolving it, including sharing my codebase etc. If there is an official (paid) Kurento support i am willing to pay for sure.

Thanks!

Mikhail

Comment: The computer that doesn't work ... what are its specs (Linux, OSX, Windows)?  Are you using Chrome or Firefox to capture the screen?  The Chrome API (and I believe the FF API) sends a blacked-out video stream when the application you're sharing is minimized.

Comment: FWIW ... we've been using the screen sharing API with zero issues for more than a year.

Comment: Windows 7. I use Electron, which includes Chrome.

Comment: Did you check what candidates get generated by both peers? Also, which ones are selected? You need to do that for both successful and unsuccessful connections.

Comment: Problem fixed itself after updating Electron version to latest. It seems like the Chrome version it used had some WebRTC problem.

Comment: @MichaelGorham any tutorial for screen sharing please